# Error: Not applicable for the "main.dart" configuration

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, emulation

I cannot run my code on any emulator in **Android studio**... I have been despritely trying to solve this issue. the section is greyed out at the top and when I press play nothing happens. Any suggestions? Btw I have tried almost everything i've seen on the internet for this issue, I assume it has to do with [Run > edit configurations]

[click here for reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSLjV.jpg)

Comment: Can you start virtual device and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Next time on opening studio click on the dropdown devic menu on the left side of "main.dart" then click on your emulator. If your emulator doesn't show up then click "refresh" and then click on yur AVD in the drop down.

After that click on the green play button then wait for a while for it to compile.

Hope this helps you, if you still don't understand drop a comment I'll send images.